# Cannot open an exe file

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe

```
import extruct 

def main():
    input("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

This is the code that I converted into an exe file with pyinstaller. If I open this file now, the exe crashes directly. At the bottom is the message:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the specified path: 'C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI801802\mf2py\backcompat-rules'"

---

It is definitely because I am importing "extruct". But I need this library for the correct code. Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work... these are the steps I took. Im using windows.  On another operating system the only changes that need to be made are the virtual environment path to the bakcompat-rules directory.

1. create a new empty directory and copy and paste your code into `main.py` file
2. `py -m venv venv`
3. `venv/Scripts/activate`
4. `py -m pip install --upgrade pip pyinstaller extruct`
5. `pyinstaller -F main.py`
6. This will create a main.spec file. open it and at the top paste the following

```
import os
data = []
parent = "./venv/Lib/site-packages/mf2py/backcompat-rules/"
for item in os.listdir(parent):
    path = os.path.join(parent, item)
    target = parent
    data.append((path, "mf2py/backcompat-rules"))
```

7. in same file in `Analysis` signature change `datas=[],` to `datas=data,`
8. `pyinstaller main.spec`
9. `dist/main.exe`

And it should run fine.